# /ah/warmup producing HardDeadlineExceededError:

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My java appengine has been running nicely for months. But the last two days I have seen 5 and now 34 HardDeadlineExceededError when doing a /_ah/warmup.

the errors are in simple classloading stuff.

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.apphosting.runtime.HardDeadlineExceededError: This request (4a25d7231dc330cc)     started at 2012/02/23 15:43:53.912 UTC and was still executing at 2012/02/23 15:46:41.239  UTC.
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-4a25d7231dc330cc(Request.java)
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:231) 
at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:273)
```

I have billing enabled with min(2)-max(5) front end instances.

what can be causes these errors?
what has suddenly changed with the GAE infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

With you current performance settings the scheduler will keep recycling idle instances over `5`, so it is likely to cause more loading request, and since there is currently an issues with loading request being intermittently slow this could cause repeated `HardDeadlineExceededError`.

You can set `max idle instance` to `Automatic` to minimize loading requests and the number of `HardDeadlineExceededError`.

The App Engine team is aware that there is intermittent issues with slow loading requests, and they are working on a general fix that will go out in the upcoming releases.

Comment: i think your correct @proppy.
i increased max instances to 7 and no error today.
it seems that the request rate overwhelmed my max of 5.
i will try setting max to auto and see how large my invoice will become!

thanks

Comment: Further investigation reveals that even with max instances to 'Auto' i still got 3 failed warmup requests due to deadlines, which caused further requests to fail.

Comment: the failed warmups are causing excessive request failure.
upto 10% of daily request are failing due to warmup failure.

why are requests being sent to dodgy warmup instances?

Comment: Looks like you didn't have any HardDeadlineExceededError in the last 32 hours.

Comment: Yeah last 2 days have been error free. But the load profile seems be the same. so can i assume that this is an Appengine issue and NOT a application issue?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer: `The App Engine team is aware that there is intermittent issues with slow loading requests, and they are working on a general fix that will go out in the upcoming releases.`

Comment: more warmup errors today

/fbconnect/update 325 19% 
/_ah/warmup 83 91% 
/task/nearbyfriendnotificationTask 44 3.4% 

whats going on?